# Substitution failure is not an error (SFINAE) for enum

Tags: c++, traits, sfinae

Is there a way to use Substitution failure is not an error (SFINAE) for enum?

```
template <typename T>
struct Traits
{
}
template <>
struct Traits<A>
{
};
template <>
struct Traits<B>
{
  enum
  {
     iOption = 1
  };
};

template <T>
void Do()
{
  // use Traits<T>::iOption
};
```

Then, `Do<B>();` works and `Do<A>();` fails. However, I can supply a default behavior when iOption does not exist.
So I separate out some part of Do to DoOption.

```
template <typename T, bool bOptionExist>
void DoOption()
{
  // can't use Traits<T>::iOption. do some default behavior 
};
template <typename T>
void DoOption<T, true>()
{ 
  // use Traits<T>::iOption
};
template <T>
void Do()
{
  // 'Do' does not use Traits<T>::iOption. Such codes are delegated to DoOption.
  DoOption<T, DoesOptionExist<T> >();
};
```

Now, the missing piece is `DoesOptionExist<T>` - a way to check whether iOption exists in the struct.
Certainly SFINAE works for function name or function signature, but not sure
it works for enum value.

Comment: Note that we undeleted this question becaus I just finished writing up my answer when you deleted it. :)

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to accomplish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can use C++11, this is completely trivial:

```
template<class T>
struct has_nested_option{
  typedef char yes;
  typedef yes (&no)[2];

  template<class U>
  static yes test(decltype(U::option)*);
  template<class U>
  static no  test(...);

  static bool const value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

The C++03 version is (surprisingly) similar:

```
template<class T>
struct has_nested_option{
  typedef char yes;
  typedef yes (&no)[2];

  template<int>
  struct test2;

  template<class U>
  static yes test(test2<U::option>*);
  template<class U>
  static no  test(...);

  static bool const value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};
```

Usage:

```
struct foo{
  enum { option = 1 };
};

struct bar{};

#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<
  has_nested_option<T>::value
>::type Do(){
}

int main(){
  Do<foo>();
  Do<bar>(); // error here, since you provided no other viable overload
}
```

Comment: I deleted as I found that the question is already answered by other posts. Still, C++11 answer looks nice.