# How to use SFINAE for enum without specifying the enum?

Tags: c++, enums, refactoring, template-meta-programming, sfinae

Using answer from
[Substitution failure is not an error (SFINAE) for enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597394/substitution-failure-is-not-an-error-sfinae-for-enum) I tried to write a code that would get enum value from a class, and if this enum value is not found it would have a fallback value. 
As I'm beginner with templates, after couple of hours I gave up and found a "solution" using macros :(

Is there a way to do the same thing without macros and without copying the code for every possible enum value?

This is what I came up with:

```
struct foo
{
    enum FooFields
    {
        enumFoo,
        enumHehe
    };
};

struct bar
{
    enum BarFields
    {
        enumHehe = 2
    };
};

#define GETENUM_DEF(testedEnum) \
template<class T> \
struct get_ ## testedEnum{\
  typedef char yes;\
  typedef yes (&no)[2];\
\
  template<int>\
  struct test2;\
\
  template<class U>\
  static int test(test2<U::testedEnum>*){return U::testedEnum;};\
  template<class U>\
  static int test(...){return -1;};\
\
  static int value(){return test<T>(0);}\
};

GETENUM_DEF(enumFoo)
GETENUM_DEF(enumHehe)

int main() {

    std::cout<<get_enumFoo<foo>::value()<<std::endl; //returns 0;
    std::cout<<get_enumFoo<bar>::value()<<std::endl; //returns -1;

    std::cout<<get_enumHehe<foo>::value()<<std::endl; //returns 1;
    std::cout<<get_enumHehe<bar>::value()<<std::endl; //returns 2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will have to define a `get_someField` for all the types you want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ requires that you define a `get_someField` for every field you want to get, but you'd have to do that with or without macros.

Playing with SFINAE is part of what is known as template meta-programming. What you are doing is effectively detecting whether the expression `T::enumFoo` is valid, and returning that value if it is, else `-1`.

To detect whether expression is valid, we can do something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

// You need void_t to avoid a warning about the lhs of the comma operator 
// having no effect. C++ 17 has std::void_t
template<class...> using void_t = void;

template<class T, class = void>
struct get_enumFoo
{
    static constexpr int value = -1;
};

template<class T>
struct get_enumFoo<T, void_t<decltype(T::enumFoo)>>
{
    static constexpr int value = T::enumFoo;
};

template<class T, class = void>
struct get_enumHehe
{
    static constexpr int value = -1;
};

template<class T>
struct get_enumHehe<T, void_t<decltype(T::enumHehe)>>
{
    static constexpr int value = T::enumHehe;
};
```

Using it (your example):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << get_enumFoo<foo>::value << std::endl; //returns 0;
    std::cout << get_enumFoo<bar>::value << std::endl; //returns -1;

    std::cout << get_enumHehe<foo>::value << std::endl; //returns 1;
    std::cout << get_enumHehe<bar>::value << std::endl; //returns 2;
}
```

It works as follows:

We define a case for SFINAE to fall back on in the case that the expression `T::enumFoo` is invalid:

```
template<class T, class = void>
struct get_enumFoo
{
    static constexpr int value = -1;
};
```

We then define the case that sees if `T::enumFoo` is valid:

```
template<class T>
struct get_enumFoo<T, void_t<decltype(T::enumFoo)>>
{
    static constexpr int value = T::enumFoo;
};
```

If `T::enumFoo` is invalid, then the `decltype(T::enumFoo)` is an invalid expression, so SFINAE kicks in and we fall back to our previous case.

If `T::enumFoo` is valid, then `decltype(T::enumFoo)` is some type, but `void_t<decltype(T::enumFoo)>` is void. So we are specializing `get_enumFoo<T, void>` to have the field `value = T::enumFoo`.

[Try it online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e7d1c80777a144f)

---

To further reduce the boilerplate behind adding new `get_field` traits, you could define a base class:

```
namespace detail {
    struct get_foo_defaultValue
    {
        static constexpr int value = -1;
    };
}
```

Then the base case would be

```
template<class T, class = void>
struct get_enumFoo
    : detail::get_foo_defaultValue
{};
```

Comment: @Graham Yes, I expect there will be people rolling back, but you don't have to *assume* I'm going to rollback. If you want to mention it that way, please phrase it more like so: "removing links to documentation, as per: <link to meta question> . Please read the meta question before rolling back the edit."